# upload time very slow with multiple file as blob uploads on Azure storage containers using Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service, multiple-file-upload

I want to store some user images from a feedback section of an app I am creating for which I am using Azure containers.

Although I am able to store the images the process is taking ~150 to 200 seconds for 3 files of ~190kb each

Is there a better way to upload the files or am I missing something here (file type used for upload maybe).

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient,ContentSettings


connect_str = 'my_connection_string'

# Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)


photos_object_list = []
my_content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type='image/png')

#Files to upload
file_list = ['/Users/vikasnair/Documents/feedbackimages/reference_0.jpg','/Users/vikasnair/Documents/feedbackimages/reference_1.jpeg','/Users/vikasnair/Documents/feedbackimages/reference_2.jpeg']

#creating list of file objects as I would be taking list of file objects from the front end as an input
for i in range(0,len(file_list)):
    photos_object_list.append(open(file_list[i],'rb'))

import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
if photos_object_list != None:
    for u in range(0,len(photos_object_list)):

        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="container/folder", blob=loc_id+'_'+str(u)+'.jpg')

        blob_client.upload_blob(photos_object_list[u], overwrite=True, content_settings=my_content_settings)
            
stop = timeit.default_timer()

print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you can do to decrease the duration of the upload:

1. Reuse `blob_service_client` for all the uploads rather than creating a new `blob_client` for each file.
2. Use [async blob methods](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_hello_world_async.py) to upload all the file in parallel rather than sequentially.

If the target blob parent folder is static, you can also [use an Azure file share with your container instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files). This will allow you to use regular file system operations to persist files to and retrieve files from a storage account.